# Не могу получить максимальное значение id в SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

У меня есть метод с данным кодом, в котором пытаюсь получить максимальное значение `id`:

```
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl)) {
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid();");

                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    return resultSet.getInt(COLUMN_ID);
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ImageReadingException(e);
        }
```

Однако, вылазит вот такая ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'id'
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.findColumn(JDBC3ResultSet.java:48)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getInt(JDBC3ResultSet.java:395)
    at com.dugin.rostislav.database.sqlite.SQLiteDB.getLastInsertId(SQLiteDB.java:124)
    ... 40 more
```

Однако, колонка точно есть (скриншот из SQLite Studio), да и при прямой выборке - аналогичный ответ!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

В чем ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: попробуй указать из какой таблицы

Comment: @ValeraKvip, аналогичная ошибка...

Comment: по-моему ругается на эту строку: `resultSet.getInt(COLUMN_ID)`

Comment: @MaxU, угу.. :)

Comment: Ну так у вас колонка не называется 'id'. дайте ей нормальное имя типа : `SELECT last_insert_rowid() as ID` вот тогда она будет так называться

Comment: Название возращённой этим запросом колонки будет скорее всего `last_insert_rowid()`. Чему равно `COLUMN_ID`? Можно в запросе дать название возвращаемой колонке: `SELECT last_insert_rowid() as id;`, которой должно совпадат с `COLUMN_ID`. ЗЫ: опоздал

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, проверил - не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извините, может мой ответ будет совем не в тему, т.к. не силен в DriverManager'ах и т.п.

1) Но почему бы просто не попробовать?

```
SELECT `id` FROM `images` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

2) из [Interface ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) и [Руководство по JDBC v.1](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/tutorial/tutorialJDBC/resultset.html)

попробуйте добавить таблицу из которой выбираете в запросе, как было отмечено ранее [Valera Kvip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195696/valera-kvip)

а дальше (точнее или)

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `id` FROM `images` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
while (resultSet.next()) 
{
 // Возврат строки
 return resultSet.getInt("id");
}
return -1;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А "просто не попробовал" потому, что не знаю SQL и писал код копипастом :)). Но большое спасибо, действительно заработало!

Comment: @bukashka101 Надеюсь вы понимаете, что этот ответ предлагает брать максимальный id из базы. И может оказаться, что максимальный id был вставлен кем то другим на момент его получения. Вот гугл например предлагает использовать встроенный метод JDBC `stmt.getGeneratedKeys()` собственно от того стейтмента который производил вставку

Comment: @Mike, ну... Тут возникает проблема: вставляю я через один и тот же DAO, а, соответственно, и `statement`. Но на этот случай я сделал метод добавления синхронизированным, а id я возвращаю, как результат выполнения метода добавления.

Comment: @bukashka101 с одной стороны @Mike прав! Хотя мне кажется что `id` будут вставляться по порядку т.к. `auto_increment`, при том что если некоторые записи будут удаляться, все равно получишь id последней имеющейся вставленной. Но есть проблема, если будет вставлена последняя записать, а потом она будет удалена, то при таком запросе будет возвращаться `id` предпоследней записи. А не последней вставленной.